# RxJava - Using flatmap when return could be null

Tags: java, rx-java

Let's use this class for the example:

```
 public static class CurrentUser{
    public static Observable<User> get(){
         //code basically returns the currently logged in User object
         //but sometimes there may not be a logged in user 
    }

    public static Observable<PutResult> logOut(){
        return get()

                //I only want to execute the following if user != null

                .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<PutResult>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<PutResult> call(User user) {
                        //delete the session token and save
                        user.removeSessionToken();
                        return DatabaseModule.getStorIOSQLite()
                                .put()
                                .object(user)
                                .prepare()
                                .asRxObservable();
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Should I just return null inside the flatmap? Are there any repercussions to this since it's expecting an Observable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should not return `null` but [`Observable.empty()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html) instead.

```
.flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<PutResult>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<PutResult> call(User user) {
        if (user == null) return Observable.empty();

        //delete the session token and save
        user.removeSessionToken();
        return DatabaseModule.getStorIOSQLite()
                .put()
                .object(user)
                .prepare()
                .asRxObservable();
    }
});
```

Comment: So, I just realized something. If I call Oberservable.empty(), onComplete gets called immediately and it ends the chain. So if the user is null, I can't do logOut().anotherOperator()

Comment: You could use `Observable.just(null)` (or some form of non-null PutResult that carries the information of a non-existing user) in that case. It doesn't complete right away, but you have to do null checks on every subsequent operator. There is also `never`, which will never complete on its own, so you have to use sth like `limit` or flatMap an `empty` into the stream eventually.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't clear what `null` you're talking about.

If you're asking whether the `Observable<PutResult>` can emit a `PutResult` that's `null`, then yes. This would result in a `null` being emitted by the outer observable.

If you're asking whether the `Observable<PutResult>` returned by the `Func1` can be null, then no. Return `Observable.empty()` instead, (or `Observable.just(null)` or similar if you need to keep track of the number of emitted items).

Answer (score 4):

In RxJava 2 null is considered to be an invalid value. You can use Maybe component in those cases , some thing like the below

```
  Maybe<Result>

   or 

  You can use flatMapMaybe<Result>
```

Comment: That's true. Also, you can use `observable.flatMapMaybe` or `single.flatMapMaybe` instead of `flatMap`.